# cannot run/get output from runtime.getruntime.exec() (android java)

Tags: java, android

I have a php executable native binaries that came from some php server apps in play market, and I tried them on my tablet using a shell app.

I'm creating a new app and trying to run it and receive the output but it doesn't work.

I've a function that does copy the assets to the device. I also have some code to test that they are there properly

```
File file4 = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/php");
file4.setExecutable(true);
s+=file4.getName();
s+=file4.exists();
s+=file4.canExecute();
s+=file4.length();
```

it does say correct filename exists, is executable and correct file length.

Now, I try to run it it doesnt give me the php output.

I've tried `php -v` for version output, doesn't work.

I've tried php `phpfile.php >> file.html` and read the file, doesn't work.

I've tried with `-f` and also without `-f` but it doesn't work.

Lastly, I tried giving the parameters and working `dir` separately to `.exec` and still it gives no proper output

**When I tried `runtime.getruntime.exec` with other commands like `/bin/cmd/ls` ... it gives a correct output.**

The php binaries do work, I've tried 2 of them on my device, none work in my app.

I would appreciate help.

```
s+=runphp();

public String runphp(){
try {
    String prog=  "./php";
    String[] env= { "-f", getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/phprun.php"}; // ">>","phpoutput.txt"
    File dir=  new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(prog,env,dir);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String line=null;
     String output="";
     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        output += line;
  }
   in.close();
   p.waitFor();
   return output;

} catch (IOException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

**The function does work for other commands**.

Comment: Tried reading from getErrorStream as well?

Comment: i have not learned to do that yet ... hang on just learned.. errm it gives a bunch of numbers?

Comment: it gives a 24 numbers between 30 and 150 ?are they errors?

Comment: @user3110739, are you reading it in the same way as you read the inputstream? Or are you somehow printing the byte values directly? Please read it exactly like you inputStream.

Comment: it says: ./php[1]: syntax error: [some garbled letters] unexpected

Comment: i did: `BufferedReader er = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream())); while((line = er.readLine()) != null) {
                output +="[" + line + "]<br>\n\n";
            }` i wonder if this is specific to the executable i have

Answer (score 1):

The method `Runtime.exec(String prog, String[] envp, File directory)` requires you to give environment in the form `name=value` in the `String[] envp`.

But you are using it to pass **arguments** to your php program.

Use the following method instead,

```
Process exec (String[] progArray, String[] envp, File directory);
```

and pass all your command line arguments too in the first array itself.

**Your command should look like:**

```
String[] progArray= {"./php", "-f", getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/phprun.php"}; // ">>","phpoutput.txt"
File dir=  new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(progArray,null,dir);
```

Comment: it says exactly the same thing: **./php[1]: syntax error: '[garbled letters]' unexpected** is it the reply of the system or the php executable i wonder?

Comment: or is it that the emulator cannot run native binaries ? but they do run the ls and other commands... aha i get what you said now.. environment vs arguments

Comment: What happens if you execute the same command using `adb shell`?

Comment: ok.... I did ADB.. it says **[./php: not executable: 32-bit ELF file]** same file runs on my tablet. is it because im trying to run it in the emulator? this adb is very neat thanks btw.

Comment: I think I should make a real apk and try to run it on the real tablet device

Comment: @user3110739, the error is because android is not able to execute `php`. Probably it was compiled for a different architecture than the emulator, such as **ARM, x86, and MIPS**. Try to create a new emulator with different architecture and try to use that.

Comment: DUDE! it totally works! thanks a lot! the emulator is very slow but it functions, now I can continue with coding!

Comment: if the emulator is slow, you can always connect a real device to adb and use it. It will be a lot faster.

Comment: The app crashes on the tablet, I'll work on it somehow, thanks Codebender.